# Combine Multiple Excel Files into 1 Workbook and Keep Formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have multiple Excel files in a directory and I am looking to combine all of them into a single file where each file is its own worksheet. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60542050/2893712) but it does not keep formatting.

The Excel files I am loading are not in a normal table format where `pd.read_excel()` will work. Also in [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) documentation, `Workbook.copy_worksheet()` can only be used to create copies **within a single workbook**.

All of the solutions I have found seem to [iterate over every row/column](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another/) and writes the cell value to the new worksheet, which does not carry the formatting.

Comment: you can use power query in excel, you will find the option in the (Data) Tab